# How can I store user information in Next.JS + Rails API backend?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, rails-api

I'm new to Next.js and React in general, I used to develop the whole application with Rails.

I want to combine rails API with Next.js. My JWT backend has an endpoint that returns a JSON object containing user information when requested with JWT token in header. In my `_app.js`, I'm trying to authenticate users using this backend by using `useState` and `useEffect` like this:

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState({})

  useEffect(function () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/auto_login', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data) // {id: 1, email: "test@example.com"}
          setUser(data)
          console.log(user) // {}
        })
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      { // some code }
    </>
  )
}
```

In my first `console.log`, it returns an object that I would like to store in `user`. However, in my second `console.log` where I expect to return the same result, I get an empty object instead.

Am I missing anything, or are there any points that I have to take into consideration as a whole? I've already tried implementing this with `async/await`, but that didn't seem to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because that effect isn't aware of the dependent objects state change.

If you did this (see code below) you'd see `user` being logged. Eg within the context of the 1st effect's 1st run, even though you're setting the `user` state, inside the effect it's not aware of the new value.

The sequence is like this.

1. Component loads
2. Effect runs with initial state of `[]` (this effectively means run once, and uses the current state, user => `{}`)
3. state `[]` => `console.log(data)`
4. state `[]` => `setUser(data)`
5. state `[]` => `console.log(user)` // currently `{}`
6. effect is done.

Look at the useEffect explanation [here](https://medium.com/recraftrelic/usestate-and-useeffect-explained-cdb5dc252baf)

```
export default function MyApp(props) {
 const [user, setUser] = useState({ email: null, id: null })

 // same useEffect / modify your existing code 
 // you could add user in here .but then the api call will fire again, 
 // thus an infinite loop could happen, so you would need to wrap 
 // the call in an if to check to prevent that, see my alterations
 useEffect(function () {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token')
    if (token && !user.id) {
      fetch('http://localhost:3001/auto_login', {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
      })
        .then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data) // {id: 1, email: "test@example.com"}
          setUser(data)
          console.log(user);
        })
    }
  }, [user]); // [] => changed to => [user]


 // new / additional useEffect 
 // alternatively this effect will trigger when 
 // this objects state changes (and you wont need the checks as per above)
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(user);
  }, [user]);  

  return (
    <>
      { // some code, e.g if you referenced user here, example. user.email, it would work. }
      { // Would probably initially be empty, when when the ajax call completes the value would/could be set }
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, you definitely saved my day!